# Log out and redirect user to login screen ASP NET MVC / C #

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a way to end my session and redirect the user to the login screen when my system gives TimeOut.

I tried to use Session.Abandon () according to some examples that I researched. But I do not know what I'm doing wrong. below is my code to do in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var redirectLocation = context.Response.RedirectLocation.ToString();

            context.Response.RedirectLocation = null;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("session_timeout;" + redirectLocation);
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");

        }
    }
```

The code runs only until: context.Session.Abandon (); and does not redirect to the login screen unless I refresh the page.

Comment: did you try 
    context.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");

insted of 
Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");

Comment: Now that you say I tried, **context.Session.Abandon();** and **context.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");**  but it does not work. i put a break point in **Session.Abandon()** and realized that the redirect is not executed..... I click the save button and the system does not respond, i would like to redirect to page login.

Comment: you are checking if it is an AjaxRequest, I dont think that the client would be redirected if it is an Ajax Request.

Comment: You may also want to kill the authentication ticket.

Comment: I do not know how to do this. I already looked for a way, but I did not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my question this way:

1 - I set a timeout time in my Web.config by adding this tag:

```
<sessionState timeout="16"></sessionState>
```

2 - I created a function in javascript that veridifca if the timeout time came to an end:

```
    var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout- 1;

    var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;

    setTimeout('SessionEnd()', sTimeout);

    function SessionEnd() {
        alert("Your session has expired");
        window.location = "/Account/SessionTimeOutLogOff";
    }
```

**Note: This function was put in my _Layout.chshtml**

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.Remove(SessionKeys.UserType);//This will remove all keys from session variable. For example, if your session contains id, name, phone number, email etc.
        HttpContext.Session.RemoveAll();//This will remove all session from application
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();            
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what I want is not to log out of the system by clicking the exit button, but leaving the system when the same der Time out.